# problem with where in codeIgniter 

Tags: php, codeigniter, where-clause

if use of this code, show me all data, all names and all ids. what do i do?
i use of codeIgniter

With respect

```
$search_customer = 1;//$this->input->post('search_customer');
$where = "id=$search_customer OR name=$search_customer";
$query = $this->db->get('customer');
$this->db->where('id', $search_customer);
$this->db->or_where('name', $search_customer);
if($query->num_rows()==0){
            echo '0';
        }else{
            $data = array();
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
               $data[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

Comment: Your SQL query is invalid. Read the good documentation CI is famous for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line runs the query:

```
$query = $this->db->get('customer');
```

before you have set your where clauses.
You probably want

```
$this->db->where('id', $search_customer);
$this->db->or_where('name', $search_customer);
$query = $this->db->get('customer');
```

If you are still having problems take a look at the sql being generated/run:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the conditions:

```
$this->db->where('id', $search_customer);
$this->db->or_where('name', $search_customer);
```

You can see on the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) that using get_where you use an associative array.

Comment: Actually if you read the docs correctly, you can see that it takes multiple sorts of input, it can also take a string, but does some magic on it, see the `where` function. (With automatic magic which wants me to walk away from codeigniter screaming, as I have done to my enjoyment thus far a few years ago).

Comment: if use of it show me all data, all names and all ids. what do i do? i edit code and putting full code, Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just as the error is telling you.
You don't have a column in your database named 'id=1'

Try using an array

```
$array = array('id'=>$search_customer);
$this->db->get_where('customers', $array);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

There's also or_where available:

```
$this->db->or_where('name', $search_customer);
```

Comment: if use of it show me all data, all names and all ids. what do i do? i edit code and putting full code, Please check again.

Comment: As Shi mentions, you should become familiar with CI documentation, it really spells out all of this quite clearly. The last thing you need here is to get the data. You have it first, which would run 'SELECT * FROM customer', the rest after is ignored. Make your get() statement last.